# Why checking the distribution of data is needed before calculating Gower distance?

Tags: machine-learning, r, clustering, similarity

I read this article([Clustering datasets having both numerical and categorical variables](https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-datasets-having-both-numerical-and-categorical-variables-ed91cdca0677)) to learn how to perform clustering on datasets with not just numerical variables.

[image: Image from the article]

Before calculating the Gower distance, distribution of data are plotted and positive skew distribution is log-transformed. (The one on the top right corner)

Anyone knows the reason of doing that? Can you explain in an easy way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log transformation is necessary to avoid data being too sparse or having high variability. In other words, log has the rule to compress data and have clean distributions, as you can see on the top right corner.
If you try to calculate the Gower distance without the log, you will see that the distances cannot be meaningful between each other.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand. But the top right corner one is not log-transformed and it has low variability(?) because the modal class is 0 - 2500. So, if log-transformation is to avoid data having high variability, it seems like the top-right corner already has low variability?  
Please correct me if i have wrong concepts.

Comment: Logs are also interesting to reduce the differences between extreme values. Some datasets may have data from 0,00001 to 10000000, and prediction or classification models could not work very well: the log can reduce those differences. However, you lose some information with a log transformation due to the floating point memory limit.

Comment: If you consider the answers somewhat usefull, don't hesitate to upvote them as acknowledgment :)